# wordpress 3.3 relative paths in CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to add an image to be a background of the header, the thing is that I don't want to add an absolute path since I'm doing this on my pc and them is to upload to my server.

should the `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>` work in the css? It is not working here.

code:

```
#branding {
    background: url("<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/background2.jpg") repeat-x repeat-y;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, you can't use PHP within a CSS file.

You can still use a relative path. This example will work if your CSS file and images directory are in the same directory. WordPress knows this is relative to the theme.

```
#branding {
    background: url("images/background2.jpg") repeat-x repeat-y;
    height: 150px;
}
```

If the images directory is in a parent of the CSS file:

```
#branding {
    background: url("../images/background2.jpg") repeat-x repeat-y;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: it's in my pc... btw I'm using the toolbox theme to build mine

Comment: So you have `localhost/yoursite/wp-content/themes/toolbox/style.css` and `localhost/yoursite/wp-content/themes/toolbox/images/background2.jpg`?

Comment: if it works in chrome, but not other browsers, it isn't a path issue. you've got something else lurking.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow @developdaly solution did not work for me, but this helped:

```
.img-div {
  background-image: url("wp-content/themes/your-theme/assets/images/your-img.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.img-div {
    background-image: url("./assets/images/your-img.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a SASS/SCSS user, I find the simplest way to solve this problem is to declare the URL as a variable in your .scss file:

```
$wpLocation: '/wp-content/themes/themename/';
```

Then reference it like this:

```
$background: url($wpLocation + "/whateverfile.jpg");
```